# Messages get lost on WebLogic WebSocket connection

Tags: java, javascript, websocket, weblogic, message

I implemented a JMS Client that is supposed to update the browser when a JMS Message arrives. Unfortunately, about 50 per cent of the messages are lost and never arrive. It is really strange. What could be the reason?

Here I post part of my code. I created the client according to the html5 websocket examples for weblogic and I have version 12.1.2. I have no errors on java nor on javascript side. The console prints Receive message from Bean: Shit happens ist printed every two seconds, but I receive only on the client every 4 seconds or even less. Why is that?

```
package com.packtpub.techbuzz.jms;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.QueueConnection;
import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.QueueReceiver;
import javax.jms.QueueSender;
import javax.jms.QueueSession;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import weblogic.websocket.ClosingMessage;
import weblogic.websocket.WebSocketAdapter;
import weblogic.websocket.WebSocketConnection;
import weblogic.websocket.WebSocketListener;
import weblogic.websocket.annotation.WebSocket;

@WebSocket(timeout = -1, pathPatterns = "/counter.ws")
public class SocketMediator extends WebSocketAdapter implements WebSocketListener, MessageListener {  
    private static SocketMediator sm;  

    public final static String JNDI_FACTORY = "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory";
    public final static String JMS_FACTORY = "jms/myConnectionFactory"; 
    private static final String RETURN_QUEUE = "jms/TestJMSReturnQueue";  
    private static final String QUEUE = "jms/myTestQueue";  
    private QueueConnectionFactory qconFactory;  
    private QueueConnection qcon;  
    private QueueSession qsession;  
    private QueueReceiver qreceiver;  
    private QueueSender qsender;  
    private javax.jms.Queue queueReturn;  
    private javax.jms.Queue queue;  
    private boolean isConnected;  

    public static SocketMediator getSm() {  
        return sm;  
    }  
    public SocketMediator() {  
        super();  
        sm = this;  
        isConnected = false;  
        try {  
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();  
            qconFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(JMS_FACTORY);  
            qcon = qconFactory.createQueueConnection();  
            qsession = qcon.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);  
            queue = (javax.jms.Queue) ctx.lookup(QUEUE);  
            qreceiver = qsession.createReceiver(queue);  
            qreceiver.setMessageListener(this);  
            qsender = qsession.createSender(queue);  
            qcon.start();  
            isConnected = true;  

            int counter = 0;

            // Use the ThreadScheduledExecutor to invoke a runnable at a later time 
            // which posts some data into the queue
            Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                             try {
                                TextMessage textMessage = qsession.createTextMessage("Shit happens");  
                                qsender.send(textMessage);
                            } catch (JMSException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                        }
                    }
                }, 2, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);



        } catch (JMSException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (NamingException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }  
    @Override  
    public void onOpen(WebSocketConnection webSocketConnection) {  
        System.out.println("New connection was created from a client " + webSocketConnection.getRemoteAddress());  
        super.onOpen(webSocketConnection);  
    }  
    @Override  
    public void onMessage(WebSocketConnection connection, String payload) {  
        // Sends message from the browser back to the client.  
        System.out.println("Does this ever actually fire?");

    }  

    @Override  
    public void onClose(WebSocketConnection webSocketConnection, ClosingMessage closingMessage) {  
        super.onClose(webSocketConnection, closingMessage);  
        System.out.println("Connection was closed from a client " + webSocketConnection.getRemoteAddress());  
    }  
    @Override  
    public void onError(WebSocketConnection webSocketConnection, Throwable throwable) {  
        super.onError(webSocketConnection, throwable);  
        System.out.println("Something went seriously wrong with client " + webSocketConnection.getRemoteAddress());  
    }  
    // Subscription for return messages  
    @Override  
    public void onMessage(javax.jms.Message msg) {  

        final String msgText;

        try {  
            if (msg instanceof TextMessage) {
                msgText = ((TextMessage) msg).getText();
            } else {
                msgText = msg.toString();
            }
            System.out.println("Received message from bean: "+msgText);  
            for(final WebSocketConnection conn : getWebSocketContext().getWebSocketConnections()){  
                    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule(
                            new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    try {
                                         conn.send(msgText);  
                                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                                    }
                                }
                            }, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            }  
        } catch (JMSException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Do I need to interpret "about 50 per cent of the messages are lost and never arrive" as "about 50 per cent of the time the onMessage() handler doesn't get fired" ? Or did you actually investigate the queue?

Comment: Check if you have a cluster setup, if so, the messages might be going to the other servers queue. You need to setup Messaging bridge in that case to resolve it.

Comment: I had the same problem if I redeployed my application without shutting down the WebLogic server.  I HAVE to follow these steps ... 1) Undeploy the app.  2) Restart the server 3) Redeploy the app.  If I don't, I'll only get 50% of my messages.  I have code just like yours.

Comment: Something else ... you may want to think about setting up a TopicReceiver as opposed to a Queue.  The first instance of your SocketMediator will acknowledge the receipt, but I don't think the rest will.

Comment: Haha, when I said I have code just like yours.  It looks like you found my post: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3543318